# Retrieving MS Access column with international name from Java (encoding)

Tags: java, ms-access

I need to import data from some legacy Access databases. I ran the code with some database file, and everything went fine. Now, I tried it with another one and the same code doesn't work.

It seems to be related to character encoding, although I didn't specify anything (and wouldn't know where to do that).

```
Double age = resultSet.getDouble("âge");
```

works on first db file, gives an SQLException with "Column not found" on another one. On the problematic database, resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnName(3) (same column) gives "?ge".

UPDATE: it seems that the result is in fact consistent between databases. The difference I saw was because the first import was run from a class in an EJB-project (I ran the main method of some class, not the EJB module in an app server). The second import was done on a new standalone project. The standalone Java project always fails with this exception, but running the same code in the first project always works.

question formulated another way here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519517/getting-ms-access-column-with-international-character-from-java

Comment: I would advise you to use `resultSet.getDouble(int)` to avoid future errors as well.

Comment: column order isn't guaranteed

Comment: You might be using the `iso-8859-1` charset in your database, well you will have to convert the string `âge` to `age` using charset converters before getting the data in that column. Another workaround is to change the charset of the database to `utf8` or `utf16`

Comment: @Rakesh: I don't know how access encodes databases internally. For decent databases, it's jdbc responsability (sometimes with configuration) to give a translated java string to the applications, so accents should appear and be decoded correctly. The strange thing is, as I said, I copy/pasted the code from one project to another one. It works (no error using "âge") in project 1 but not in 2.

Comment: Check the charset of the java source file. Are you using Eclipse? If yes you can compare both project source files using context-menu Properties option.

Answer (score 0):

Manipulating an Access database via the JDBC-ODBC Bridge and the Access ODBC driver will only work reliably for accented characters that are included in the Windows-1252 character set. In those cases you **must** set the character encoding of the Java source file to `cp1252` in Eclipse (or set the character encoding of the project to `windows-1252` in NetBeans). If your Java source file is encoded as UTF-8 then your code will NOT work if accented characters are involved. (For more details see my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21044401/2144390).)

For more complete Unicode character support consider using [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) instead.

Comment: They do exist in both charsets, that's not the problem.