# JDBC-ODBC Bridge queries to Access fail when they have accented characters

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, odbc, jdbc-odbc

I'm sending a query through the JDBC-ODBC Bridge to an Access database from Java, like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM localities WHERE locName='" + cityName + "'"
```

When cityName is a normal string with no accented characters, the resultset is correct.
But when cityName happens to be something like `LEÓN`, `SAHAGÚN`, that is with accented characters in them, then I get no results. It seems like the query fails in these cases.
The same queries when run in MS Access work all right, I also tried with Ms Data Acces SKD and these queries work perfectly.

They only fail when passing through the JDBC-ODBC Bridge.
As I understand, Java uses UTF-8 for strings and so does Access. And they both use Unicode.
Does anyone know any solution to this problem?

Comment: So, did you get this sorted out?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your Java source file is encoded as UTF-8 so when the `cityName` string contains `LEÓN` it is encoded as

```
L  E  Ó     N
-- -- ----- --
4C 45 C3 93 4E
```

That is not how Access stores the value. Access does store characters as Unicode, but it does not use UTF-8 encoding. It uses a variation of UTF-16LE encoding where characters with code points U+00FF and below are stored in a single byte, and characters with code points above U+00FF are stored as a Null (0x0) value followed by their UTF-16LE byte pair(s). In this case `Ó` is U+00D3, which is below U+00FF, so Access stores all four characters of the string as single bytes:

```
L  E  Ó  N
-- -- -- --
4C 45 D3 4E
```

The net effect is that the encoding of the string in the Access database is the same as it would be for the ISO 8859-1 character set.

This can be confirmed with the following Java code which uses the JDBC-ODBC Bridge. It fails to find the desired record when the Java source file is encoded as `UTF-8`, but it works when the Java source file is encoded as `cp1252` in Eclipse:

```java
import java.sql.*;

public class accentTestMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String connectionString = 
                "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};" + 
                "DBQ=C:\\__tmp\\test\\accented.accdb;";
        try {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
            PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM localities WHERE locName=?");
            String cityName = "LEÓN";
            stmt.setString(1, cityName);
            stmt.execute();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
            if (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(String.format("Record found, ID=%d", rs.getInt("ID")));
            }
            else {
                System.out.print("Record not found.");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

If you can make do with supporting only the accented characters represented in the `cp1252` character set then you should be able to simply use `cp1252` as the encoding setting for your Java source file(s).

On the other hand, **if you really need full Unicode character support with an Access database then the JDBC-ODBC Bridge is not going to get the job done for you**. This is a long-standing interoperability issue between the JDBC-ODBC Bridge and the Access ODBC driver, and it is not going to be fixed. (More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20982205/2144390).)

In that case you might want to consider using [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) which is a pure-Java JDBC driver for Access. The corresponding code using UCanAccess with a UTF-8 encoded source file would be

```java
// assumes...
//     import java.sql.*;
Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/__tmp/test/accented.accdb");
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(
        "SELECT ID FROM localities WHERE locName=?");
ps.setString(1, "LEÓN");
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
if (rs.next()) {
    System.out.println(String.format(
            "Record found, ID=%d", 
            rs.getInt("ID")));
}
else {
    System.out.println("Record not found.");
}
```

For more information on using UCanAccess, see the related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21955256/2144390).

Another solution would be to use [Jackcess](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/) to manipulate the Access database like so (again, the Java source file is encoded as UTF-8):

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.*;

public class accentTestMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Database db;
        try {
            db = DatabaseBuilder.open(new File("C:\\__tmp\\test\\accented.accdb"));
            try {
                Table tbl = db.getTable("localities");
                Cursor crsr = CursorBuilder.createCursor(tbl.getIndex("locName"));
                if (crsr.findFirstRow(tbl.getColumn("locName"), "LEÓN")) {
                    System.out.println(String.format("Record found, ID=%d", crsr.getCurrentRowValue(tbl.getColumn("ID"))));
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Record not found.");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                db.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use PreparedStatement.

I have just tested MS Access Northwind database with Jython 2.5 which uses JDBC-ODBC bridge:

```
c = db.createStatement()
TRADH = u'Tradi\xe7\u0103o Hipermercados'
pstm = db.prepareStatement("SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName FROM customers WHERE CompanyName=?")
pstm.setString(1, TRADH)
rs = pstm.executeQuery()
while (rs.next()):
    try:
        s1 = rs.getString(1)
        s2 = rs.getString(2)
        print('[%s] [%s]' % (s1, s2))
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        print('[%s] [%s] !!!' % (s1, repr(s2)))
c.close()
```

In your code it will look like:

```
pstm = db.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM localities WHERE locName=?");
pstm.setString(1, locName);
rs = pstm.executeQuery();
...
```