# Java ODBC MS-Access Unicode character problems

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, odbc, jdbc-odbc

I am trying to make an application that connects to an Access database. I have made it through making the ODBC connection of my Java program with an .mdb file but I have this problem with Unicode characters. If a record is written in English (Latin) characters then the .mdb file recognizes the characters but if the record is written in Greek then some weird characters appear and I can't get the record with the ResultSet object. Can someone help?

Comment: Some dbs have a different data type for non-ascii data. Java strings are Unicode by design

Comment: the problem is while i get the record from my db java understand the non-ascii letters and convert them to Greek, but that happens when i get all the records..That means that i cant search a specific name for example cause it cant be recognized

Comment: ok but how can i use UCanAccess?

Comment: i am using neatbeans ide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JDBC-ODBC Bridge will not work correctly with the Access ODBC driver when strings contain Unicode characters whose code point is above U+007F. Greek characters fall into that category, so the JDBC-ODBC Bridge approach will not work for you. (More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21044401/2144390).) Also, the JDBC-ODBC Bridge has been removed from Java (since Java 8).

To get proper support for Greek characters I would recommend using [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html). For an overview of how to set that up, see another of my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21955257/2144390).

Once your project has been configured to use UCanAccess you can work with your Access database using code like this:

```java
Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/__tmp/unicode.accdb");
String language = "Greek";

PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(
        "SELECT [word], [english_equiv] " +
        "FROM [vocabulary] " +
        "WHERE language=?");
ps.setString(1, language);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    System.out.println(String.format(
            "\"%s\" is %s for \"%s\".", 
            rs.getString("word"),
            language,
            rs.getString("english_equiv")));
}
rs.close();
ps.close();

String newWord = "ηλεκτρονικός υπολογιστής";
String newEnglishEquiv = "computer";
ps = conn.prepareStatement(
        "INSERT INTO [vocabulary] ([word], [language], [english_equiv]) " +
        "VALUES (?,?,?)");
ps.setString(1, newWord);
ps.setString(2, language);
ps.setString(3, newEnglishEquiv);
ps.executeUpdate();
System.out.println(String.format(
        "\"%s\" has been added to the table.", 
        newWord));
```

That code produces the following console output:

```
"γιορτή" is Greek for "feast"
"ηλεκτρονικός υπολογιστής" has been added to the table.
```

(Translations courtesy of [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/).)

Comment: May i ask another question.. When i try to execute the rs.last(); command , it gives me this error :net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: feature not supported. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

If you call ResultSet.first() or ResultSet.last(), you have to properly initialize Statement or  PreparedStatement:

```
PreparedStatement ps =conn.prepareStatement("SELECT *  FROM T1",ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
```

@Gord, thanks for all you are doing about UCanAccess.